# Drool Workbench Tomcat giving error

Tags: git, drools, kie-workbench

I have downloaded latest version of Drool Workbench 6.3 war file for tomcat. after deploying same will get the error.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bash" (in directory "C:\Users\vp19433"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.readPipe(FS.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS_Win32.discoverGitPrefix(FS_Win32.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.gitPrefix(FS.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader$Default.openSystemConfig(SystemReader.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.build(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.InitCommand.call(InitCommand.java:113)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.util.JGitUtil.newRepository(JGitUtil.java:104)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.rescanForExistingRepositories(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:407)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:371)
    at org.uberfire.java.nio.fs.jgit.JGitFileSystemProvider.<init>(JGitFileSystemProvider.java:343)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:356)
```

I came to know that there is a problem with Jgit Jar file. they have change the code, which will run without git.

Source : https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commit/ec6ec3b10fb1ef8dd73a499d0b1f7a7d711b84dd

But From where i get the updated jar so will replace with existing one and able to run Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can build it yourself from the sources:

```
git clone git@github.com:eclipse/jgit.git
cd jgit
mvn clean package
```

Or you can get the jars from a maven repository like Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jgit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22org.eclipse.jgit%22

Hope it helps,